# jQuery slideDown and slideUp Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slidedown, slideup

I'm trying to make a menu using  tags, and you can see it here, along with source code: http://jsfiddle.net/6wqjq/10/

But the problem is like this...try to click Menu Item One, then click Sub Menu Item One. What happens to me (using Chrome) is that slideDown actually slides the element too much, then locks it in where I want it. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery slideDown Snap Back Issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5943994/jquery-slidedown-snap-back-issue).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's a fix by specifying a width of a submenu: http://jsfiddle.net/6wqjq/12/
(in this example I made it 300px)